# Finding Exact Values of Specific Infinite Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Prove that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(n/2^n)=2$ and that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^2/2^n)=6$.

Thoughts:

I have a feeling that if someone shows me how to do one, I'll be able to figure out the other. So far in my proof, I proved these two convergent by the ratio test. I attempted to work with the series in a similar fashion to that of geometric series but was unsuccessful.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots$, so $x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. Now take $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without derivatives:

$$2S_1:=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)2^{-(n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n2^{-n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}=S_1+2.$$

$$2S_2:=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^22^{-n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)^22^{-(n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^22^{-n}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty n2^{-n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\\
=S_2+2S_1+2.$$

---

Just for fun,

$$2S_3=S_3+3S_2+3S_1+2$$ $$2S_4=S_4+4S_3+6S_2+4S_1+2$$so that

$$S_3=26,\\S_4=150.$$

The general rule is obviously

$$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\binom ki S_i+1.$$

A few more:

$$1^*, 2, 6, 26, 150, 1082, 9366, 94586, 1091670, 14174522, 204495126, 3245265146, 56183135190, 1053716696762, 21282685940886, 460566381955706, 10631309363962710, 260741534058271802, 6771069326513690646, 185603174638656822266\cdots$$

(https://oeis.org/A076726 but the first one)

Comment: very cool. I am curious though, why do the indices not seem to matter as much? You have 2S1 = S1 + 2, but the rightmost S1 starts from 0, not from 1 and thus cannot be S1.

Comment: Oh nevermind haha I see that that first term is just 0.

Comment: @EthanZell: you get it. This works for all sums but the last, and this is why we have $2$ instead of $S_0=1$.

Comment: One must be careful with manipulations like this, as they can lead to nonsensical statements such as $\sum n=\frac{-1}{12}$.

Comment: @zz20s: in this case, the decay is geometric, so you can rely on the manipulations with closed eyes. Manipulations on generating series also need careful justifications.

Comment: Of course. I'm just warning the OP that less justified manipulations are dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ for all $|x|<1$.

Differentiating both sides, we have

$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Differentiating again, we get

$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^n=x\cdot\frac{(1-x)^2+2x(1-x)}{(1-x)^4}=x\cdot\frac{1-2x+x^2+2x-2x^2}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{x(1-x^2)}{(1-x)^4}$$

Now, let $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Do not forget to adjust for your indexes, as they do not equal $0$.

Comment: When I utilize the second derivative's formulation at x= 1/2, I find the sum is equal to 1/4, which is apparently untrue. Am I skipping a step? @zz20s

Comment: Correction: I find sum = 4, not 1/4

Comment: Fixed. I took the derivative incorrectly.

Comment: Would anyone care to explain the downvote?